# How to implement "gm convert -profile" via GraphicsMagick C API?

Tags: c, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, color-space

I want to convert an input JPEG image to sRGB color profile.

This cli variant works well:

```
gm convert src.jpg -profile sRGB.icc -strip dst.jpg
```

But this variant doesn't work:

```
FILE *f = fopen("./sRGB.icc", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
unsigned char *profile = malloc(fsize);
n = fread(string, 1, fsize, f);
fclose(f);

res = ProfileImage(image, "ICM", profile, fsize, MagickFalse); // also try "ICC"
// got MagickFail
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt newest libgraphicsmagicks.a with liblcms.a and all was well.

```
unsigned char sRGB_icc[] = {...}; // save sRGB.icc in source code
unsigned int sRGB_icc_len = ...;

ProfileImage(image, "ICM", sRGB_icc, sRGB_icc_len, MagickTrue); // "-profile"
ProfileImage(image, "*", NULL, 0, MagickFalse); // "-strip"
```